# How can I improve the performance of core service files loading in XPM?

Tags: experience-manager

Under the network tab in chrome, I can check the time taken to load a particular file. How can I increase the performance of files such as Workflow.svc, IsEnabled.svc etc, which are taking more time to load now?

Answer (score 3):

Which version are you running?

There's no magic `performance=high` setting for any of these services, you need to improve the process as a whole.

For instance, they may be taking too long to read data from the DB, in which case you should make sure DB maintenance is happening regularly, etc. In Web 8+ you can use [The Content Manager Tracing Tool](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-B80A337C-1D7A-440D-BBE6-A02D7EA89981) to show the actions happening in the system and time take for each, and then use this info to optimize the subsystems where it's taking too long.